# SQL Query Optimization

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I have a table that has 50 columns, will it take less time to use a statement like

```
SELECT id,name,description FROM table
```

or will it be the same as if I write

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

Comment: Note that even if you want to select all the columns, it's still better to write out the column names - what if you add a 50mb blob to each row later on? You don't want to be pulling that down unless you absolutely need to. It's also just better for query management.

Comment: *'time to **use** a statement'*? 'time to **run** a statement', maybe? or maybe even 'time to transfer the result set after running a statement'?

Comment: @Andriy M, it actually is not only about transferring data, it is also about reading it, so I'd use "time to run" (perform? execute?) rather than "time to transfer".

Comment: Besides it may make the maintenance of the code easier as it makes clearer the intention of the statement, and the columns which are actually needed (in case the database structure evolves in the future, changing/renaming columns, moving them to another table for (de)normalization...).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always return the least number of columns possible to satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need all the columns, it's certainly best to only select the ones you need. While it probably won't take MySQL more time to locate the rows, it will certainly be faster to send the results back to the client (since there is less data to return).

Comment: It is worth noting that *client* is PHP script in this case (rather than user's browser).

Comment: @binaryLV: in *any* case, having big chunks of data moving from any one place to another will be slower than moving smaller chunks - even in-memory.

Comment: @jcinacio, sure, I'm not arguing against that. What I tried to say is that some people might think that "*client*" always means "*browser*", and "*php*" always means "*server*". So they might read this answer and think "oh, moving data from server to client is slow, but that's OK - I do not send data to client, so it does not matter", but this is wrong, as PHP is a client, when talking about sending data between DB and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting all columns always takes longer than selecting the columns you actually want. Try them out in PHPMyAdmin or something and have a look at the time they take to complete. For this, using a bigger table is a good idea to get times greater than `0.001` seconds and the like.

James